# JavaScript in WordPress to make Smooth Scroll effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, smooth-scrolling

I'd like to have Smooth Scroll effect in this site http://konstantin.raccoonbox.com/osta-palveluita/. The site is WordPress site and it is a problem. I don't know how to connect JavaScript/jQuery in WordPress. All the WordPress plugin that I have seen are either useless, bad, or messes the whole site. That is why I don't want to use them.

I would love to have a smooth scroll in that site when pressing those orange buttons ("WordPress Sivut" and "Koodatut Sivut"). Or if you go to the very bottom of the site you will see "Raccoonbox tarjoaa ilmaisen kyydin ylös" -link (Trans. Raccoonbox offers a free ride to top) which is written in WordPress footer.php file.

How can you do smooth scroll in wordpress without a plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress usually loads jquery by default. The site you listed is using jquery 1.11.3. If you open up header.php you can add the smooth scroll script there or add it in your functions.php file which is the preferred approach.

[Wordpress enqueue and functions.php](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script)

Take a look at this site [learning jquery](http://www.learningjquery.com/2007/10/improved-animated-scrolling-script-for-same-page-links), He created a plugin you can download as well

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. Which script to put where?

Comment: Download the script using the link above. Upload the script to your themes js folder (if you don't have a folder named js then you can create one e.g. wp-content/theme/yourtheme/js/jquery-smoothscroll.min.js) If you open functions.php you can add   `code` <?php

function my_scripts_method() {
 wp_enqueue_script( ‘smooth-scroll’, get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.smooth_scroll.js', array( 'jquery' ), ‘1.5.6’, TRUE);
 );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method' );

?>
`code`